# Deploy spring app in Websphere get Error 404: SRVE0190E

Tags: spring, deployment, websphere, web-deployment, websphere-7

I'm trying to deploy a spring + angularJS app (packaging as war) into websphere (7.0.0.25), but even for the sample app I cloned from spring, I always get **Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found**. And even for the spring app, I have to explicitly specify index.html in the URL, otherwise I get the same error. But the angular side is tolerable, can anyone help me with the spring side?

The sample application is: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-convert-jar-to-war-maven.git

After doing "mvn clean package" in "/gs-convert-jar-to-war-maven/complete" to get the war, I follow the steps here to upload and deploy the war in websphere:
http://www.packtpub.com/article/deploying-applications-on-websphere-application-server-7.0-part1

I also tried this post to set the custom properties but still didn't work: http://frightanic.com/software-development/solution-to-error-404-srve0190e-on-websphere-6-1/

Also, both my app and the sample spring app don't have a web.xml as spring will take care of it. Both apps work fine in jetty and Tomcat. Only websphere has the problem. Besides, I don't know how to manually configure a web.xml if that will be the solution (need to be pointed to more resources).

The URLs I tried but failed to access the app are:

localhost:9080

localhost:9080/gs-convert-jar-to-war-0_1_0_war

localhost:9080/someAppName

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Login to the admin console and check what context root is defined for application. Check in systemOut.log if it starts correctly and attach stacktrace with exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that websphere 7 doesn't support some spring annotations/classes. My solution is to write a web.xml file and turn off spring auto-configuration.